# Overland SnapServer 510 - Constant Beep

Tags: network-attached-storage, hardware-raid, custom-errors

I have an Overland SnapServer 510 with GOS 6.5.029.
I cleaned it, reseated the memory, same sticks, same slots.
But now, when I boot, it is emitting a constant beep.
I can't find anything about "tones" or "beep codes" in the SnapServer GuardianOS 6.5 Administrator's Guide.

Any help, insights or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm certain that this is a *contact support* situation or *replace hardware* situation.

The concern is that this is a VERY old system - circa 2006?
I remember when these were [released 13 years ago](https://www.itworld.com/article/2822344/adaptec-adds-opteron-based-nas.html).

Either way, hardware errors typically result in audible alarms on equipment like this. Check power supplies, disk health, fans and the front LCD display for hints on what's wrong. Read the [hardware install manual](http://download.adaptec.com/pdfs/user_guides/500_Series_FRU_Procedures.pdf).

You can try calling support, but at this point, the equipment is over a decade old. I wouldn't expect much support.